# How to save licensing data from a decommissioned VMware server?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server

My current VMware (Vsphere? ESXi?) hardware is being repurposed and its virtual machines are moved to VirtualBox.
I want to save the licensing data - so if the need arises in the future - I could create a new VMware server.

I know that I can get my VMware server license information with `vim-cmd vimsvc/license --show`.

**Which licensing files/information do I need to save, So I could create a VMware server sometime in the future?**

Edit:

```
[root@localhost:~] vmware -vl
VMware ESXi 6.0.0 build-3029758
VMware ESXi 6.0.0 Update 1
```

Comment: What version of vSphere are you running? https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The VMware server was inherited, and I don't know much of its internals/contents. I put the version I found below the _Edit_ of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if the ESXi's are connected to a VCenter server (making vSphere), someone should had received and registered a license code (or at least, in my former organization it worked like this, not sure if there are other options, maybe online license server?), that you should introduce to your vCenter Server and your ESXi's.

Check if, in your vSphere Client/Web Client, you have the section Administration/Licensing, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: VMware vSphere Client]

Once there, from my understanding, you should be able to see the license description and I think also the code, that should be presented in something like this (although this is the vCenter Client interface, but it should be similar), taken from a VMware guide:

[image: vSphere Licenses Manager]